# Why won't civicrm/greeter load?

Tags: extension

I'm starting to learn extensions with http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension . I already need trouble-shooting advice. I can't figure out how to get civicrm/greeter to load. If I try to browse to it, I get the main civicrm page instead. Can anyone help me find the step I've missed.

Answer (score 2):

I found my problem. civicrm/greeter didn't load because I had a typo (extentions as opposed to extensions) in my Extension Resource URL. Once I fixed that, it all fell into place.